# Diamond Sutra in Tibetan, Sanskrit, and/or Japanese

Tags: sutras, tibetan-buddhism, zen, chanting, tibetan

Does anyone know where I can find a version of the Diamond Sutra that is in one of these three formats:

1. Classical Tibetan with Romanized Tibetan and English
   [image]
2. Devangari with Romanized Sanskrit and English
   [image]
3. Japanese with Romaji and English
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> एवं मया श्रुतम् evaṃ mayā śrutam
>
> एकस्मिन् समये भगवान् श्रावस्त्यां विहरति स्म जेतवनेऽनाथपिण्डदस्यारामे
>   महता भिक्षुसंघेन सार्थं त्रयोदशभिर्भिक्षुशतैः संबहुलैश्च
>   बोधिसत्त्वैर्महासत्त्वैः ekasmin samaye bhagavān śrāvastyāṃ viharati
>   sma jetavane'nāthapiṇḍadasyārāme mahatā bhikṣusaṃghena sārthaṃ
>   trayodaśabhirbhikṣuśataiḥ saṃbahulaiśca bodhisattvairmahāsattvaiḥ
>
> अथ खलु भगवान् पूर्वाह्णकालसमये निवास्य पात्रचीवरमादाय श्रावस्तीं
>   महानगरीं पिण्डाय प्राविक्षत् atha khalu bhagavān pūrvāhṇakālasamaye
>   nivāsya pātracīvaramādāya śrāvastīṃ mahānagarīṃ piṇḍāya prāvikṣat
>
> अथ खलु भगवान् श्रावस्तीं महानगरीं पिण्डाय चरित्वा कृतभक्तकृत्यः
>   पश्चाद्भक्तपिण्डपातप्रतिक्रान्तः atha khalu bhagavān śrāvastīṃ
>   mahānagarīṃ piṇḍāya caritvā kṛtabhaktakṛtyaḥ
>   paścādbhaktapiṇḍapātapratikrāntaḥ
>
> पात्रचीवरं प्रतिशाम्य पादौ प्रक्षाल्य न्यषीदत्प्रज्ञप्त एवासने
>   पर्यङ्कमाभुज्य ऋजुं कायं प्रणिधाय प्रतिमुखीं स्मृतिमुपस्थाप्य| अथ खलु
>   संबहुला भिक्षवो येन भगवांस्तेनोपसंक्रामन् उपसंक्रम्य भगवतः पादौ
>   शिरोभिरभिवन्द्य भगवन्तं त्रिष्प्रदक्षिणीकृत्य एकान्ते न्यषीदन्
>   pātracīvaraṃ pratiśāmya pādau prakṣālya nyaṣīdatprajñapta evāsane
>   paryaṅkamābhujya ṛjuṃ kāyaṃ praṇidhāya pratimukhīṃ smṛtimupasthāpya
>   atha khalu saṃbahulā bhikṣavo yena bhagavāṃstenopasaṃkrāman
>   upasaṃkramya bhagavataḥ pādau śirobhirabhivandya bhagavantaṃ
>   triṣpradakṣiṇīkṛtya ekānte nyaṣīdan
>
> तेन खलु पुनः समयेनायुष्मान् सुभुतिस्तस्यामेव पर्षदि
>   संनिपतितोऽभूत्संनिषण्णः अथ खल्वायुष्मान्
>   सुभूतिरुत्थायासनादेकांसमुत्तरासङ्गं कृत्वा दक्षिणं जानुमण्डलं
>   पृथिव्यां प्रतिष्ठाप्य येन भगवांस्तेनाञ्जलिं प्रणम्य भगवन्तमेतदवोचत्
>   आश्चर्यं भगवन्, परमाश्चर्यं सुगत, यावदेव तथागतेनार्हता सम्यक्संबुद्धेन
>   बोधिसत्त्वा महासत्त्वा अनुपरिगृहीताः परमेणानुग्रहेण tena khalu punaḥ
>   samayenāyuṣmān subhutistasyāmeva parṣadi saṃnipatito'bhūtsaṃniṣaṇṇaḥ
>   atha khalvāyuṣmān subhūtirutthāyāsanādekāṃsamuttarāsaṅgaṃ kṛtvā
>   dakṣiṇaṃ jānumaṇḍalaṃ pṛthivyāṃ pratiṣṭhāpya yena bhagavāṃstenāñjaliṃ
>   praṇamya bhagavantametadavocatāścaryaṃ bhagavan, paramāścaryaṃ sugata,
>   yāvadeva tathāgatenārhatā samyaksaṃbuddhena bodhisattvā mahāsattvā
>   anuparigṛhītāḥ parameṇānugraheṇa
>
> आश्चर्यं भगवन् यावदेव तथागतेनार्हता सम्यक्संबुद्धेन बोधिसत्त्वा
>   महासत्त्वाः परीन्दिताः परमया परीन्दनया| तत्कथं भगवन्
>   बोधिसत्त्वयानसंप्रस्थितेन कुलपुत्रेण वा कुलदुहित्रा वा स्थातव्यं कथं
>   प्रतिपत्तव्यं कथं चित्तं प्रग्रहीतव्यम् āścaryaṃ bhagavan yāvadeva
>   tathāgatenārhatā samyaksaṃbuddhena bodhisattvā mahāsattvāḥ parīnditāḥ
>   paramayā parīndanayā| tatkathaṃ bhagavan bodhisattvayānasaṃprasthitena
>   kulaputreṇa vā kuladuhitrā vā sthātavyaṃ kathaṃ pratipattavyaṃ kathaṃ
>   cittaṃ pragrahītavyam
>
> एवमुक्ते भगवानायुष्मन्तं सुभूतिमेतदवोचत्साधु साधु सुभूते,
>   एवमेतत्सुभूते, एवमेतद्यथा वदसि अनुपरिगृहीतास्तथागतेन बोधिसत्त्वा
>   महासत्त्वाः परमेणानुग्रहेण परीन्दितास्तथागतेन बोधिसत्त्वा महासत्त्वाः
>   परमया परीन्दनया तेन हि सुभूते शृणु, साधु च सुष्ठु च मनसि कुरु,
>   भाषिष्येऽहं तेयथा बोधिसत्त्वयानसंप्रस्थितेन स्थातव्यं यथा
>   प्रतिपत्तव्यं यथा चित्तं प्रग्रहीतव्यम् एवं भगवन् इत्यायुष्यान्
>   सुभूतिर्भगवतः प्रत्यश्रौषीत् evamukte bhagavānāyuṣmantaṃ
>   subhūtimetadavocatsādhu sādhu subhūte, evametatsubhūte, evametadyathā
>   vadasi anuparigṛhītāstathāgatena bodhisattvā mahāsattvāḥ
>   parameṇānugraheṇa parīnditāstathāgatena bodhisattvā mahāsattvāḥ
>   paramayā parīndanayā tena hi subhūte śṛṇu, sādhu ca suṣṭhu ca manasi
>   kuru, bhāṣiṣyehaṃ te-yathā bodhisattvayānasaṃprasthitena sthātavyaṃ
>   yathā pratipattavyaṃ yathā cittaṃ pragrahītavyam evaṃ bhagavan
>   ityāyuṣyān subhūtirbhagavataḥ pratyaśrauṣīt
>
> भगवानस्यैतदवोचतिह सुभूते बोधिसत्त्वयानसंप्रस्थितेनैव
>   चित्तमुत्पादयितव्यम्यावन्तः सुभूते सत्त्वाः सत्त्वधातौ सत्त्वसंग्रहेण
>   संगृहीता अण्डजा वा जरायुजा वा संस्वेदजा वा औपपादुका वा रूपिणो वा
>   अरूपिणो वा संज्ञिनो वा असंज्ञिनो वा नैवसंज्ञिनो नासंज्ञिनो वा, यावान्
>   कश्चित्सत्त्वधातुः प्रज्ञप्यमानः प्रज्ञप्यते, ते च मया सर्वेऽनुपधिशेषे
>   निर्वाणधातौ परिनिर्वापयितव्याः bhagavānasyaitadavocatiha subhūte
>   bodhisattvayānasaṃprasthitenaiva cittamutpādayitavyam-yāvantaḥ subhūte
>   sattvāḥ sattvadhātau sattvasaṃgraheṇa saṃgṛhītā aṇḍajā vā jarāyujā vā
>   saṃsvedajā vā aupapādukā vā rūpiṇo vā arūpiṇo vā saṃjñino vā asaṃjñino
>   vā naivasaṃjñino nāsaṃjñino vā, yāvān kaścitsattvadhātuḥ
>   prajñapyamānaḥ prajñapyate, te ca mayā sarvenupadhiśeṣe nirvāṇadhātau
>   parinirvāpayitavyāḥ

See the rest of the Sanskrit text here: http://ntireader.org/taisho/t0235.html (this source also has it in Chinese, in case you wanted it in that language).

Use this converted to generate Devanāgari script: [Transliteration Tool -- ashtangayoga.info](https://www.ashtangayoga.info/philosophy/sanskrit-and-devanagari/transliteration-tool/#iso_iast_kolkata/devanagari/xn--bhagavnasyaitadavocatiha%20subhte%20bodhisattvaynasaprasthitenaiva%20cittamutpdayitavyam-yvanta%20subhte%20sattv%20sattvadhtau%20sattvasagrahea%20saght%20aaj%20v%20jaryuj%20v%20sasvedaj%20v%20aupapduk%20v%20rpio%20v%20arpio%20v%20sajino%20v%20asajino%20v%20naivasajino%20nsajino%20v%2C%20yvn%20kacitsattvadhtu%20prajapyamna%20prajapyate%2C%20te%20ca%20may%20sarve'nupadhiee%20nirvadhtau%20parinirvpayitavy%20-xr4akoi5am802cdb2amsjyecedcjcgdchiklpjdbpnzvdmi303mj2q5b636a7b0ej67425yvkhapa1poa7ex46dmcj3a0cmqk34lma6ck9l454absd)